# LFSR: finding the period for an irreducible Polynomial

Tags: lfsr

From what I understand an LFSR produces a maximal length sequence if its characteristic  polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ is irreducible, i.e. if it cannot be factored and the smallest integer $k$ for which $p(x)$ divides $x^k – 1$ is $2^n – 1.$

I understand $2^n -1$ has to do with the period, but how is it calculated whether the polynomial is irreducible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the property you mention

> $p(x)$ of degree $n$ cannot be factored, and divides $x^k-1$ for the first time when $k=2^n-1$

means the polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ is *primitive*. If $p(x)$ cannot be factored into a product of polynomials of lower degree then it is *irreducible*. It is enough to consider irreducible polynomials of lower degree (like prime numbers) as possible factors.

Therefore one could check whether $p(x)$ factors by methods similar to checking whether a number is prime. However, the following helps:

> For $i ≥ 1$ the polynomial $x^{2^i}-x \in \mathbf{F}_2[x]$
>   is the product of all monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbf{F}_2[x]$ whose degree divides $i$.

So, you could compute $x^{2^n}-x$ modulo $p(x)$ by the division algorithm and declare $p(x)$ irreducible if the answer is zero.

Comment: @Ayo, does this answer your question?